# Why is using <!DOCTYPE html> causing problems with height attribute with % value of a table element?

Tags: html

I wrote a HTML file to create a table that occupies 80% of the width and height of the browser window. Here is the code without `<!DOCTYPE html>` that produces the correct output:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table, td {border:1px solid black; width:80%; height:80%}
        td {width:33.33%; height:33.33%}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I add `<!DOCTYPE html>`at the top, I don't get the correct output; only the width of the table occupies 80% of the width of the browser window.The height of the table uses the minimum amount of space needed.

I have tried this in Chrome and Edge browsers. I am using VS Code as my editor.

Edit: If I give height a value in px, then it works correctly.

Comment: Add closing tag as well </html>

Comment: Closing tags are optional for most elements, including `<html>`, so that is not the issue. You have an extra space in your directive. It's supposed to look like this: `<!DOCTYPE html>`. I don't know if that is the problem, but it is an error.

Comment: head, body { height:100%; }

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to copy-paste </html> originally. And I only used a space in `<!DOCTYPE html>` because it was being counted as comment in `<code></code>`.

Comment: Put in simple terms, modern HTML5 behaves differently than tag soup from the late 1990s. That has nothing to do with your text editor, seriously.